# Jquery "read more" works on raw text but not paragraphs

Tags: jquery

I have this Jquery that I use to show/hide text on my site. But I can´t seem to make it include paragraphs. As soon as I use < p > on text, the Jquery leaves that part out and does not hide it/show it. Is there a way to make it include paragraphs?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var showChar = 600;
  var ellipsestext = "...";
  var moretext = "Læs mere";
  var lesstext = "Luk afsnit";
  
  $('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();
    if (content.length > showChar) {
      var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
      var h = content.substr(showChar - 1, content.length - showChar);
      var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
      $(this).html(html);
    }
  });

  $(".morelink").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
      $(this).removeClass("less");
      $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("less");
      $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="info-2deltbrodtekst">
  <article class="restaurantimg"></article>
  <article class="tekst">
    <div class="comment more">
      <h2 class="navn">Restaurant bla bla</h2>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, est malis laboramus ea, te usu adhuc impedit ceteros. Nemore eloquentiam sea an, tempor efficiantur ei pri. Mei error repudiare an, partem menandri tincidunt per ei. Quo ut mazim vivendum gloriatur, duo nobis aeterno ei, ad
      dicta dicunt maiestatis vix. Eu ridens civibus nostrum quo, quo legere nostrud voluptatum an, tale wisi persius ex per.
      <p> Ad qui doming saperet torquatos. Disputando dissentiet et usu. Nec semper oblique platonem ad, in mea molestiae neglegentur. Eum augue everti et, eam dicunt epicurei delectus cu. Mel ut stet nihil abhorreant, et posse malis sadipscing vim.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, this may help:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var showChar = 600;
  var ellipsestext = "...";
  var moretext = "Læs mere";
  var lesstext = "Luk afsnit";
  
  $('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();
    if (content.length > showChar) {
      var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
      var h = content.substr(showChar - 1, content.length - showChar);
      var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
      $(this).html(html);
    }
  });

  $(document).delegate(".morelink", "click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
      $(this).removeClass("less");
      $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("less");
      $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Here I'm using `delegate()` to bind the click event on the dynamically added contents link.